# How to add libgdx rendered object into current layout.xml view

Tags: android

How to add libgdx rendered view into current android xml layout

e.g

LinearLayout>

```
        <com.libgdxView.obj
            android:id="@+id/sheet"
            android:layout_width="1152dp"
            android:layout_height="576dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
            />
```

/LinearLayout>

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.libgdxView.obj.**YourClassName**
        android:id="@+id/sheet"
        android:layout_width="1152dp"
        android:layout_height="576dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
        />
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution...

// Create the layout
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

```
    // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    // Create the libgdx View
    View gameView = initializeForView(new YouSpinMeRound(), false);
    // Add the libgdx view
    layout.addView(gameView);
```